# Creating a file counter that includes hidden files

Tags: bash, bash-script

As part of a programming assignment I need to create a piece of code that will count the number of files and directories (including hidden) recursively. I'm not allowed to use the commands `-R`, `find` or `du`.

I understand that I can use:

```
listAllFiles() {
local dir=$1
local file
directoryCounter=0
fileCounter=0
hiddenFileCounter=0
hiddenDirectoryCounter=0

for file in "$dir"/*; do
    if [[ -d $file ]]; then
        listAllFiles "$file"
        directoryCounter+=1
    else if [[ -f $file ]]
        fileCounter+=1
   else if [[hidden directory]]
        hiddenDirectoryCounter+=1
   else if [[hiddenfile]]
        hiddenFileCounter+=1
    fi
done}
```

Is there a way for me to include hidden files and directories in this else if statement.

Comment: Note that you are required to put a space before ']]' -- it needs to be a distinct word.

Comment: `[[ -d x ]]` returns true if `x` is a symlink to a directory, you need `[[ -d x && ! -L x ]]`.

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` the easiest way is to run `shopt -s dotglob`, which will tell `bash` to include hidden files in globs.

If you don't want to do that (e.g. using a shell without that feature), you can just use the following globs: `.[!.]* ..?* *`.  The apparently complexity is to avoid matching `.` and `..`.  The first glob matches 2-character or longer hidden files that begin with `.` but not `..`.  The second one matches 3-character or longer hidden files that begin with `..`.  The final one is the normal glob for non-hidden files.

> Is there a way for me to include hidden files and directories in this else if statement.

Actually it's the `for` statement you should be looking at.  All you need to do is change `"$dir"/*` to also include the other 2 glob patterns I described above.

Comment: `dotglob` includes hidden files _except_ `.` and `..`

Answer (score 1):

You could so something like:

```
shopt -s nullglob
n=0
count() {
  for i in "$1"/* "$1"/.*; do
    if [ "${i##*/}" = . ] || [ "${i##*/}" = .. ] || [ -L "$i" ] || [ ! -d "$i" ]; then
      n=$(($n + 1))
    else
      count "$i"
    fi
  done
}
count .; echo "$n"
```

The only *bashism* being the `shopt` command above. It doesn't detect file system loops as `find` would but at least, it doesn't follow symlinks.

Answer (score -3):

Well this is not strictly programming, but:

```
$ i=$(ls -al | wc -l); echo $i - 3 | bc
```

works like a champ!